# BitStream for Python fails to install

Tags: windows-7, pip

I'm trying to install the bitstream Python package via pip on my windows7 machine. But it fails with:

```
 Q:\python>pip install bitstream
 Collecting bitstream
   Using cached bitstream-2.4.0.tar.gz
     Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
     Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
       File "C:\Users\vm\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-jdkts06o\bitstream\setup.py", line 5, in <module>
    import ConfigParser
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ConfigParser'

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\vm\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-jdkts06o\bitstream\
```

But ConfigParser is already installed !

```
Q:\python>pip install configparser
Requirement already satisfied: configparser in c:\users\vm\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bitstream` is Python 2.7 only, do not install it with Py 3.6.

Comment: is there an equivalent for py3 ?

Comment: [bitstring](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bitstring), [BitVector](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/BitVector).